# Effect of 発 in 発殴られる

Tags: expressions

I have the following part in a sentence:

> 増田に発殴られて

The 発殴られて is being translated as with one hit.
So I can understand why it is not simply 殴られる. But is 発殴れる a fixed term or is 発 a more common modifier such as 出す in e.g.　歩き出す?

Comment: You sure that's not a typo for 一発?

Comment: @Jimmy I'm not sure about that, as the expression is only used once in the text. But as for Kanji alternatives that are pronounced the same (no furigana was provided BTW) as はつ the choices are at least extremely limited

Comment: Without reading the given English translation, I also thought this was obviously a typo for 一発殴られて.

Comment: If it is of any help the sentence is from the short story 不快指数79 by 赤川次郎. Unfortunately, I cannot find any version of the story on the internet.